# My concatenation in Azure .json is not working as desired

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to deploy a load balancer template in which I port in various names to form a concatenation. This is so that the parameters template affects the naming of back end address pools and other outputs. My current concatenation code is this:

```
"[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', variables('loadBalancerName'), '/frontendIpConfigurations/', variables('subnet1name'), '-FrontEnd'))]"
```

However, when I attempt to run this in Jenkins, I get the following error message:

```
"Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/test-networks-hub-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/test-firewall-lb' at line '1' and column '2581'. 'Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': function requires exactly one multi-segmented argument which must be resource type including resource provider namespace. Current function arguments 'Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/,test-firewall-lb,/frontendIpConfigurations/,test-firewall-subnet,-FrontEnd'
```

It seems like the resourceId is not recognised because it is not being concatenated properly. I checked the Microsoft guidance, but I can't seem to work out where I am going wrong.

Can anyone see my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out I just had a bracket in the wrong place. The correct syntax is this:

```
"[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', variables('loadBalancerName')), '/frontendIpConfigurations/', variables('subnet1name'), '-FrontEnd')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove concat() and just use the resourceID function, e.g.

```
[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/frontendIpConfigurations', variables('loadBalancerName'), concat(variables('subnet1name'), '-FrontEnd'))]
```

Learning that function/pattern will help quite a bit when you start using resources in other groups or subscriptions.